# How to convert a string that contains HTML encoding characters to NSData?

Tags: html, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, nsdata

I need to convert this string

```
"{
"name":"Tsubasa En La Liga",
"description":"T\u1ebfp sau b\u1ed9 tsubasa El classico\u2026anh \u0111\u00e3 tr\u1edf l\u1ea1i, g\u1eb7p l\u1ea1i nh\u1eefng b\u1ea1n b\u00e8 v\u00e0 \u0111\u1ed1i th\u1ee7 c\u0169 v\u00e0 c\u1ed1 g\u1eafng \u0111\u01b0a \u0111\u1ed9i tuy\u1ec3n nh\u1eadt \u0111o\u1ea1t chi\u1ebfc c\u00fap v\u00f4 \u0111\u1ecbch"
}"
```

to a NSData object.
I used

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] length:[string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

or

```
NSData* data =[data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

And then save data to a Core Data entity.
But when I read data from the entities the result is utf8 encoded.

```
"{
"name":"Tsubasa En La Liga",
"description":"Tếp sau bộ tsubasa El classico…anh đã trở lại, gặp lại những bạn bè và đối thủ cũ và cố gắng đưa đội tuyển nhật đoạt chiếc cúp vô địch"
}"
```

I don't want the string encoded to utf8.
I want the original string should be save to Core Data entity.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix that by escaping your backslashes. use double back-slash `\\`.